# why is chart.CumReturns diff to cumsum?

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I have a matrix of returns for x assets.

I can plot the cumulative performance like this:

```
pnls.cum<-apply(pnls.allin , 2 , cumsum)
plot(pnls.cum[,1],type="l")
```

or

```
chart.CumReturns(pnls.allin[,1])
```

But the graphs are subtly different (highs/lows etc) . Is there reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chart.CumReturns` uses geometric chaining (a product) by default, not arithmetic chaining (a sum).  Just set `geometric=FALSE`:

```
chart.CumReturns(pnls.allin[,1], geometric=FALSE)
```